# Jsoup parse and nested tags

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm learning Jsoup and have this HTML:

```
 [...]
 <p style="..."> <!-- div 1 -->
   Content
 </p>
 <p style="..."> <!-- div 2 -->
   Content
 </p>
 <p style="..."> <!-- div 3 -->
   Content
 </p>
 [...]
```

I use Jsoup.parse() and document select("p") for catch "content" (and works nice). But...

```
 [...]
 <p style="..."> <!-- div 1 -->
   Content
 </p>
 <p style="..."> <!-- div 2 -->
   Content
 </p>
 <p style="..."> <!-- div 3 -->
   Content
   <p style="..."></p>
   <p style="..."></p>
 </p>
 [...]
```

In this scene, I see that Jsoup.parse() convert this code to:

```
 [...]
 <p style="..."> <!-- div 1 -->
   Content
 </p>
 <p style="..."> <!-- div 2 -->
   Content
 </p>
 <p style="..."> <!-- div 3 -->
   Content
 </p>
 <p style="..."> <!-- div 4 -->
 </p>
 <p style="..."> <!-- div 5 -->
 </p>
 [...]
```

How can I keep order of nested paragraphs with Jsoup (div 4 & 5 inside of div 3)?

---

Add a example:

**HTML file**:

```
 <html>
 <head>
    <title>Title</title>
 </head>
 <body>
    <p style="margin-left:2em">
            <span class="one">Text</span>
            <span class="two"><span class="nest">Text</span></span>
            <span class="three"></span>
    </p>
    <p style="margin-left:2em">
            <span class="one">Text</span>
            <span class="two"><span class="nest">Text</span></span>
            <span class="three"></span>
    </p>
    <p style="margin-left:2em">
            <span class="one">Text</span>
            <span class="two"><span class="nest">Text</span></span>
            <span class="three"></span>
            <p style="margin-left:2em"></p>
            <p style="margin-left:2em"></p>
    </p>

 </body>
 </html>
```

**Java code**:

```
Document doc = null;
doc = Jsoup.connect(URL_with_HTML).get();
System.out.println(doc.outerHtml());
```

**Return**:

```
<html>
<head> 
 <title>Title</title> 
</head> 
<body> 
 <p style="margin-left:2em"> <span class="one">Text</span> <span class="two"><span class="nest">Text</span></span> <span class="three"></span> </p> 
 <p style="margin-left:2em"> <span class="one">Text</span> <span class="two"><span class="nest">Text</span></span> <span class="three"></span> </p> 
 <p style="margin-left:2em"> <span class="one">Text</span> <span class="two"><span class="nest">Text</span></span> <span class="three"></span> </p>
 <p style="margin-left:2em"></p> 
 <p style="margin-left:2em"></p> 
 <p></p>   
</body>
</html>
```

Is correct this? I using Jsoup 1.6.1. I understand that Jsoup should return nested paragraphs instead of previous return.

Comment: It seems a bug. If you could, please file it.

Comment: I add example with files/codes for clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nested paragraphs do not exist in HTML. The prior paragraph is closed automatically since [Jsoup  implements the WHATWG HTML5 specification](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues/436#issuecomment-52142683):

1. A `p` tag is automatically closed by any of the following: `address`, `article`, `aside`, `blockquote`, `div`, `dl`, `fieldset`, `footer`, `form`, `h1`, `h2`, `h3`, `h4`, `h5`, `h6`, `header`, `hgroup`, `hr`, `main`, `menu`, `nav`, `ol`, `p`, `pre`, `section`, `table`, or `ul`. Therefore `<p><div></div> becomes <p></p><div></div>`.
2. An end tag whose name is `p` (ie `</p>`) that does not have a corresponding start tag is a parse error and is replaced with `<p>`. Therefore `<span></span></p>` becomes `<span></span><p>`.

So jsoup is correct and your HTML is invalid.

Be sure to comprehend that your HTML is invalid because you have too many `</p>` and not because "nesting" paragraphs. Nesting cannot happend because they get auto-closed. But the later coming `</p>` is obsolet because the "corresponding" `<p>` was already auto-closed before.

Comment: Very thanks! HTML code is third-part (not mine), I don't modified it. At now, how can I fix this problem? (replace nested paragraph to span class="p", for example, if problem is in parse() method?)

Comment: @FabianBarney, Jsoup does not care about valid HTML tags. Please test with `Jsoup.parse("<html><body><xxx></xxx></body></html>")`.

Comment: But jsoup cares about "real world" parsing HTML. And auto-closing `<p>` and undefined behaviour of nested block elements inside `<p>` is real world parsing. You would have much trouble with absolute legal HTML like `...<p>First paragraph<p>Second paragraph...` otherwise. Not closing `<p>` is legal!

Comment: @Manz jsoup is very much parsing like browsers do. Examine your page with tools like Firebug and you'll see that your HTML got interpreted the same. (Auto-closed p-tags etc.) We cannot tell you how to fix it since it is not clear what your desired output should look like. If you need nested block-elements then you cannot use `<p>` as an outer tag. Use `<div>` instead ...

Comment: @FabianBarney, Thank you, I didn't know that until now.

Comment: @FabianBarney The problem is that I can't modify HTML code (isn't mine). I need system for replace this code (with Jsoup or other) before parse() method.

Comment: So what's the problem using jsoup's code then and modify that one? It is the same what every major browser produces from that invalid input. Why you cannot use the "cleaned" code from jsoup?

Answer (score 0):

Hj, I understand the original question. But I think it is a bug of Jsoup (not yours). Since this is a simple example:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <p></p>
        <p>
            <div></div>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

But Jsoup parses this:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <div></div>
        <p></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you could, please file this bug so the author can fix it  :-)

P.S: Just a word "hi", stackoverflow does not allow it?

Comment: I suspect that isn't a bug. If replace "suspicious" <p> for <span> works fine. Maybe, <p> inside of <p> is HTML-incorrect and Jsoup understand try fix it?

Comment: As my experience, Jsoup does not care about HTML keywords. I've been using Jsoup to parse XML, it worked fine. You can test with `Jsoup.parse("<html><body><xxx></xxx></body></html>")`.

Comment: A `<p>` is not allowed to contain any block element! So the "simple" example is invalid (X)HTML.

Comment: Having similar issue with p tag alone. When i Parse this HTML `<p><p class="a">Sample Text </p>Sample 1<br>
Sample 2
</p>`    I got output as `<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <p></p>
  <p class="a">Sample Text </p>Sample 1
  <br> Sample 2 
  <p></p>
 </body>
</html>`