# JSOUP Document Structure issue HTML

Tags: java, html, html-parsing, jsoup

```
            String url = request.getParameter("url");
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            Elements web = doc.childern.select("*");
            for(Element ele : web)
            {
                if(ele.hasText())
                ele.text("hello");

            }
```

when i print the document its restructuring like
                    
                    hello
                     hello
                       hello

instead of

```
                       <html>
                        <head>
                         <title>
                         hello
                         </title>
                         <body>
                             hello
                           </body>
                          </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

But where's the problem?

if you want to except the `head`-tag from your edits you can use this:

```
Elements web = doc.body().select("*");
```

This gives you only the body-elements which you can change now.

Comment: The problem is after parsing the tags are not structured correctly         like <html><head><title></title></head><body></body></html>  instead it will be like <html></html><head></head><body></body>

Comment: especially `<html></html>` looks strange to me. What version of Jsoup are you using (1.7.2 is the current one)? As a test, please call the `normalise()`-method on your document.

Comment: well the problem is this... check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9853880/jsoup-parse-and-nested-tags

Comment: What version of jsoup are you using?